# MessagingStyle.Message setData method not working in the notification

Tags: android

I am working on my SMS/MMS app and using the android messaging notification style. I want to make it so that when a user sends an image I can add it to the notification using the MessagingStyle.Message.setData(uri, mimeType) method. The issue is that when I do this nothing happens. I am giving it the uri to the mms database holding the image and the mime type of "image/jpeg" My only thought is that the notification does not have access to the MMS uri (as only my app is default and therefore only my app can access that data) but I am unsure how I could grant that to the system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Oh god, I just spent hours on the same problem. It turns out that this magic requires two conditions:

- You must use a mime type of an image starting with `image/`, the rest of the string is ignored.
- The image message must be added first